# How to check if I'm inserting in db from java

Tags: java, sql, database, oracle, error-handling

just a guide here, please!

I want to insert some values in my db, from java
I have my oracle prepared statement and stuff and it inserts ok, but my other requirement it's to send via email the fields that for some reason werent insert.

So, Im thinking making my method as int and return like 0 if theres an error 1 if its ok, 2 if some fields didn't insert ... etc... BUT

I'm lost figuring how to bind it, I mean if there's an error in the catch from sql in java i can put like

```
catch (SQLException e) {// TODO Auto-generated catch block 
            e.printStackTrace();
            return result = 0;
```

And obviously i can put an error message and stuff where i call it, but how will i know in which item stops and then retrieve the rest of the fields that weren't insert...

any idea? anyone has an example?

Thanks in advance

Comment: I don;t think any sql statement can partially insert the data

Comment: You should analyze some of the `SQLException` codes and based on that return a message to user instead of returning a plain 0. Note that you can create your own `Exception`s and based on the `SQLException` code you can rethrow one of yours to ease the code maintenance.

Comment: You should not use `int` values to indicate errors, instead you could rethrow the exception or simply don't catch it. And if you really want return values that indicate the state of success, use `enum`. It's more OOP and less error-prone.

Comment: JunedAhsan I didn't understand what u said...
@LuiggiMendoza the message to the user its not a problem, I catch my java code in .as, and in the .as i handle the messages for the user ok...
But maybe I wasn't clear... what i want is, 
when you insert data, for some reason, maybe invalid type or invalid format i dunno , then the sql statement stops and the rest of the values that werent inserted, those are what I want to retrieve and save them in something an array i dunno and send that to the user via email " this values weren't inserted cause of blabla"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all try to do as much validations possible in Java and identify the bad records before persisting them in database, you can catch those records before they hit database and send email.

In case you are worried about db level issues e.g. contrainst etc, then you need to choose Performance vs Flexibile Features

Option1 : Dont use batch insert one record at a time, whatever fails you can send email, this is bad from performance perspective but will solve your purpose

Option2 : Divide your records into batches of 50 or 100, whatever batch fails you can report that whole batch failed, this will also report some good records, but you will have information about what was not persisted.

Option3 : Divide your records into batches, if a batch fails try saving one record at a time for that particular batch, that ways you will be able to identify bad record and performance will be optimized, this will require more coding and testing.

So, you can choose what ever suits you, but I would recommend following:

1. Do maximum validations in Java
2. Split into smaller batches and use Option 3.

Cheers !!

Comment: This is mostly what I wanted, a guide a suggestion, thanks for your time @SachinThapa ...
Yup, I'll try those 2 steps... maybe just with lots of validation before hit the query, will be simpler for now

Comment: @Raf0c - Glad was able to help.

Answer (score 0):

When you have an insert you insert all fields included in the statement; or, none.  So if throw an exception when running your statement, then you would send an email.

If no exception is thrown then you would assume that it has worked.

Alternatively, after running the insert, you could then attempt to do a select to check to see if the data you inserted was actually there.

Comment: So what u are saying is that it insert all of it, or nothing ?

There is no way to know if it stops at some line?

I know my query is inserting if all of it it's ok, but i wanna know if there's a way to know if there's an error, where stopped and then retrieve them

Comment: If you do not throw an exception, then in general, the statement works.  I say in general as you may have some kind of fluky implementation.

Comment: I do throw an exception, yes, if there was an exception i would send an email, I just wanted to know if there's a way to retrieve the insert value that for some reason had a fault and therefore it doesnt insert anything, then send the email with information and maybe something like " the insertion stops at : bla bla bla" where bla bla is the insert value with a fault

Answer (score 0):

If the statement failed then none of your field will be inserted, because oracle internally does a rollback to maintain consistency in your data.

Comment: Yes, I can see that, but, do you know if there is a way to know in which statement have a fault? and then retrieve that one ?